How can I connect my dryer to this misplaced wall box?
Home builder seems to have put this pipe too close to the wall, so it is making things very difficult to get anything connected to it in order to exhaust properly. It originally had this dryer elbow box type ducting installed, but I'm not sure that it is entirely correct to use. (I will use it if I could get the dang thing back on!)
There is such a tight space between the back wall and the lip on the elbow is making it extremely difficult to fit. Not sure which side I should be trying to install if attempting to reuse the old elbow ducting, so I labeled A and B directional arrows.
Any recommendations on what I need to do to get this connected properly? I went and bought a new piece of 4" ducting that I had hoped would fit easier and better since it is thinner, but still having problems fitting around the pipe in the wall do to the odd shaping and bent metal.
Diameter should be 4", but I sure as heck can't get anything connected around it.
Ducting Photos


Get rid of the box and attach the flex duct directly to the conduit in the wall.

The crimped (smaller) ends of duct pipe are always supposed to be downstream of the uncrimped (larger) ends, the opposite of what your image shows. The vertical pipe in the wall looks tapered, which is not correct. Or it is oval duct, in which case you need a transition. The crimped end of whatever fitting you use there should go INSIDE the pipe in the wall, not outside.

What do you mean by "too close to the wall"? How exactly is the dryer port misaligned?

@kreemoweet, that's not always true. Most flex duct is installed over the rigid duct so it can be secured with a strap clamp. Here I think the expectation is that only flex would be connected. Yes, it's backward with respect to flow and a potential lint catcher, but it's accessible and should be cleaned regularly anyway.

If the wall box and the elbow are not compatible, you must replace or stop using one of them.  You don't need a wall box, you don't need that wall box, you don't need an elbow, you don't need that big boxy elbow.  If you like the elegance of a wall box and a rigid elbow, find ones that are compatible.  There are a thousand ways to do this.  Products galore.  Just do something else.
Also, the point of a wall box like that one is often to provide a close-to-wall fit for the dryer.  Having a large round hose connected to it sticking straight out, as you do, negates that entirely.  Once you solve the elbow problem, if this matters to you, look at periscope-style flat vents.
